# “The three shooters algorithm”

Tags: probability, algorithms

As requested at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111313/the-three-shooters-algorithm?noredirect=1#comment46504341_29111313 I have moved that topic into here:

Like the title says, you've got 3 'shooters': shooter **A**, **B** and **C**. 
The rules are the following:

Each one has a different chance to hit: 

Shooter **A** will hit for **100%** of the times. 

Shooter **B** will hit for **80%** of the times. 

And shooter **C** will hit for **50%** of the times.

Each shooter will factually die after being hit once and will be removed.

Each shooter will prioritize hitting the shooter still alive with the highest chance to hit. f.e: if all shooters are alive: **C** shoots **A**, **B** shoots **A**, **A** shoots **B**.

Each shooter may only shoot one bullet when it's his turn.

Each new game that starts will let one of the three shooters start at random.

Once a shooter played his turn (and if that shooter is not the only one left standing), the next shooter to play will be picked at random and the one who just played his turn can't be picked again(meaning that the shooter who just played can't play two turns consecutively but after the next turn he may play again).

A game can only end once there's a winner in the form of the last shooter standing.

---

What I was wondering about is - **what's the average win ratio for each shooter** after.. Lets say, 2,000,000 games? 

**Do the following results I've gathered seem correct?**(And before you'll ask for my calculations to be provided, I've gathered those results through code in the above link, so I doubt it'd be of any use here, please correct me if I'm wrong :p)

a: 0.2344525(23.4%), b: 0.3187745(31.8%), c: 0.446773(44.6%).

We were given no formal answer in our class and just about everyone I checked up with came with a different answer of his own.

Comment: I have answered the question in a google doc so far, waiting for this question to be posted here. I'll post it as an answer later, but for now it might help other people write their own answer. Here it is: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y4qLWWECj0kJnxm8Q6u__2594Su1WYRRz0tKdfAExH8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You should probably just post your doc as the answer btw, I doubt anyone's still calculating this :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my calculations, the probabilities of winning for each shooter match the statistical results that you obtained. Therefore, I believe you can trust your program.

Here is the exact results I found:

- probability of A winning: $\frac{165}{702} \approx 0.23504$
- probability of B winning: $\frac{224}{702} \approx 0.31909$
- probability of C winning: $\frac{313}{702} \approx 0.44587$

Here is the problem as a graph:

[image]

- blue nodes are states where the next shooter needs to be chosen among those written in CAPS. Each leaving edge corresponds to the choice of one shooter (equal probability for each choice).
- green nodes are states where everyone is alive, and one of the shooters is about to shoot (the one in CAPS). Each leaving edge corresponds to the shooter hitting or missing, and is labeled with the probability for it to happen.
- orange nodes are similar to green nodes, but only 2 shooters are alive. Each leaving edge corresponds to the shooter hitting or missing, and is labeled with the probability for it to happen
- red nodes are end game states, containing the winner

We can find the exact probabilities by resolving the probability graph completely: we just need to express the starting node in terms of the end-game nodes.

If it were a tree, the calculations would be really simple: simply multiply the probabilities of each edge until you reach a red node.
However we can notice 2 loops, because B and C can miss each other forever:

- a big purple loop, on the left
- a small orange loop, on the right

So we need to solve some equations (which is quite simple).

$$\color{blue}{ABC} = \frac{1}{3} \color{green}{Abc} + \frac{1}{3} \color{green}{aBc} + \frac{1}{3} \color{green}{abC}$$

We can develop each of the 3 green nodes now.

### When A shoots first

\begin{align}
\color{green}{Abc} &= \color{orange}{aC} \\
                   &= \frac{1}{2} \color{orange}{Ac} + \frac{1}{2} c \\
                   &= \frac{1}{2} a + \frac{1}{2} c \\
\tag{1}
\label{Abc}
\end{align}

### When B shoots first

$$\color{green}{aBc} = \frac{1}{5} \color{blue}{AbC} + \frac{4}{5} \color{orange}{bC}\tag{2}\label{aBc-init}$$

Here we can expand the orange loop:

\begin{align}
\color{orange}{bC} &= \frac{1}{2} \color{orange}{Bc} + \frac{1}{2} c \\
                   &= \frac{1}{2} (\frac{4}{5} b + \frac{1}{5} \color{orange}{bC}) + \frac{1}{2} c
\end{align}

Which can be reduced to:

$$\color{orange}{bC} = \frac{4}{9} b + \frac{5}{9} c \tag{3}\label{bC}$$

We can also expand the blue node AbC:
\begin{align}
\color{blue}{AbC} &= \frac{1}{2} \color{green}{Abc} + \frac{1}{2} \color{green}{abC} \\
                  &= \frac{1}{4} a + \frac{1}{4} c + \frac{1}{2} \color{green}{abC} \text{$\quad$(injecting \eqref{Abc})}
\tag{4}
\label{AbC}
\end{align}

We can now plug \eqref{bC} and \eqref{AbC} into \eqref{aBc-init}:

$$\color{green}{aBc} = \frac{1}{20} a + \frac{16}{45} b + \frac{89}{180} c + \frac{1}{10}\color{green}{abC}\tag{5}\label{aBc-reduced}$$

### When C shoots first

\begin{align}
\color{green}{abC} &= \frac{1}{2} \color{blue}{ABc} + \frac{1}{2} \color{orange}{Bc} \\
                   &= \frac{1}{4}\color{green}{Abc} + \frac{1}{4}\color{green}{aBc} + \frac{1}{2} \color{orange}{Bc}
\tag{6}
\label{abC-init}
\end{align}

We can solve the $\color{orange}{Bc}$ loop easily using our result from \eqref{bC}:

$$\color{orange}{Bc} = \frac{1}{5} \color{orange}{bC} + \frac{4}{5} b = \frac{8}{9} b + \frac{1}{9} c \tag{7}\label{Bc}$$

Now we can plug \eqref{Abc}, \eqref{aBc-reduced}, and \eqref{Bc} back into \eqref{abC-init}:

$$\color{green}{abC} = \frac{11}{80} a + \frac{8}{15} b + \frac{219}{720} c + \frac{1}{40}\color{green}{abC}$$

Here is our purple loop! We can then reduce this to:

$$\color{green}{abC} = \frac{11}{78} a + \frac{320}{585} b + \frac{219}{720} c\tag{8}\label{abC-reduced}$$

### Putting everything together

We can now finish expanding \eqref{aBc-reduced} using \eqref{abC-reduced}:

\begin{align}
\color{green}{aBc} &= \frac{1}{20} a + \frac{16}{45} b + \frac{89}{180} c + \frac{1}{10}\color{green}{abC}\\
                   &= \frac{50}{780} a + \frac{240}{585} b + \frac{369}{702} c
\tag{9}
\label{aBc-final}
\end{align}

Back to the starting point, we can now plug all the green node equations and find the final probabilities mentioned at the beginning of the answer:

\begin{align}
\color{blue}{ABC} &= \frac{1}{3} \color{green}{Abc} + \frac{1}{3} \color{green}{aBc} + \frac{1}{3} \color{green}{abC}\\
                  &= \frac{165}{702} a + \frac{224}{702} b + \frac{313}{702} c
\end{align}

Comment: Using the graph in the link, by traversing the loop from $aBc$ once I would compute $aBc = \frac45bC + \frac1{10}Abc + \frac1{20}Bc + \frac1{40}Abc + \frac1{40}aBc,$ cancel $\frac1{40}aBc$ on each side and multiply by $\frac{40}{39}.$ Now you have $aBc$ in terms of $bC,$ $Bc,$ and $Abc,$ which are easily found. A similar technique gives $abC$ in terms of $bC,$ $Bc,$ and $Abc,$ although you can short-circuit that loop once you know $aBc.$